# How to mock MassTransit Header values in unit test using NSubstitute

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rabbitmq, masstransit, nsubstitute

I'm trying to create a unit test that will test my MassTransit (RabbitMq) consumer.  My consumer is expected a bus header key called `UserName`.  I've simplified my consumer class as follows.  I need to find a way to mock the bus header data otherwise the test will always raise an exception when  it executes `context.Headers.TryGetHeader("UserName", out object value)`

I'm using the *NSubstitute* mocking library. So how do I mock the `ConsumeContext<MyDataObject>` type, and set a mock header value?  I prefer a solution with *NSubstitute*

```
public class MyDataObjectCommand
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}

// Consumer class
public class MyConsumer : IConsumer<MyDataObjectCommand>
{
    private readonly IHubContext<MessageHub> _hubContext;

    public MyConsumer(IHubContext<MessageHub> hubContext)
    {
        _hubContext = hubContext;
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<MyDataObjectCommand> context)
    {
        var myProperty = context.Message.MyProperty;
        var userName = TryGetHeader(context, "UserName");
        DoSomethingWith(_hubContext, myProperty, userName);
    }

    private string TryGetHeader(ConsumeContext<MyDataObjectCommand> context, string key, bool errorOnNull = true)
    {
        if (context.Headers.TryGetHeader(key, out object value))
        {
            return Convert.ToString(value);
        }

        if (errorOnNull)
        {
            throw new MyConsumerException(_reportName, $"{key} is not found", _hubContext);
        }

        return null;
    }
}


// Unit Test (I'm using XUnit)
public class MyConsumerTests
{
    private readonly IHubContext<MessageHub> _hubContext;

    public MyConsumerTests()
    {
       _hubContext = Substitute.For<IHubContext<MessageHub>>();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task ShouldConsume()
    {
        // arrange
        var mockDataObject = new MyDataObjectCommand() { MyProperty = "x" };

        var harness = new InMemoryTestHarness();
        harness.Consumer(() => new MyConsumer(_hubContext));

        // I need to mock header values on ConsumeContext<MyDataObjectCommand> object here
        // but how do I do it using NSubstitute?
        // context.Headers["UserName"] = "Bob";  ??

        await harness.Start();
        try
        {
            
            // act
            await harness.InputQueueSendEndpoint.Send(mockDataObject);

            // assert
            Assert.True(await harness.Consumed.Any<MyDataObjectCommand>());
            Assert.False(await harness.Consumed.Any<Fault<MyDataObjectCommand>>());
            //Assert.Equal(context.Header["UserName"], "Bob"); How do I do the assertion??
        }
        finally
        {
            await harness.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t *mock* header values when using MassTransit, you just have to set them when you’re sending the message using the test harness. There is absolutely *zero* need for a mocking framework.

```csharp
await harness.InputQueueSendEndpoint.Send(mockDataObject, 
    context => context.Headers.Set(“UserName”, “Bob”));
```

The header will then be available on the `ConsumeContext` when the message is delivered to the consumer.